# Data queried from Cassandra cannot be filtered on same column again (InvalidQueryException)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to query a large chunk of data by time from cassandra, and then use spark Datasets to get smaller chunks to process at a time, however, the application fails with an invalid query exception:

```
WARN  2018-11-22 13:16:54 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5, 192.168.1.212, executor 0): java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT "userid", "event_time", "value" FROM "user_1234"."data" WHERE token("userid") > ? AND token("userid") <= ? AND "event_time" >= ? AND "event_time" >= ? AND "event_time" <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: More than one restriction was found for the start bound on event_time
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:323)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:339)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$17.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:366)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$17.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:366)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: More than one restriction was found for the start bound on event_time
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:41)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:28)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:108)
        at com.datastax.driver.dse.DefaultDseSession.prepare(DefaultDseSession.java:278)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.PreparedStatementCache$.prepareStatement(PreparedStatementCache.scala:45)
```

This is the piece of code I am trying to execute:

```
case class RawDataModel(userid: String, event_time: Long, value: Double)
var dtRangeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis()
var dtRangeStart = (dtRangeEnd - (60 * 60 * 1000).toLong)

val queryTimeRange = "SELECT * FROM user1234.datafile WHERE event_time >= " + dtRangeStart

val dataFrame = sparkSession.sql(queryTimeRange)

import sparkSession.implicits._
val dataSet: Dataset[RawDataModel] = dataFrame.as[RawDataModel]

dataSet.show(1)



dtRangeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis()
dtRangeStart = (dtRangeEnd - (15 * 60 * 1000).toLong)

val dtRangeData = dataSet.filter(dataSet("event_time").between(dtRangeStart, dtRangeEnd))

dtRangeData.show(1)
```

**Note**: This is not a DataSets problem since I have tried to swap them with DataFrames with no difference. I thought this was a lazy evaluation problem at first with two different bounds being lazily applied at the same time but the dataSet.show(1) command should call an early aggregation and avoid cascaded evaluation

Comment: It seems like spark merges `sparkSession.sql(queryTimeRange)` and `dataSet.filter(dataSet("event_time").between(dtRangeStart, dtRangeEnd))` into one command. Could you persist the dataframe (`dataFrame.persist`) and force the evaluation (something like `dataFrame.rdd.count`) between these commands?

Comment: @AlekseyIsachenkov your suggestion has certainly worked. So the hunch was right, it is a lazy evaluation problem, forcing the evaluation works. I am skeptical of the cost of doing this in a production grade application, any suggestions?

Comment: Basically, it depends on your data size and your cluster capabilities. Persist with MEMORY_ONLY mode costs almost nothing except memory for caching. But even DISK_ONLY mode doesn't slow down your code too much. Just don't forget to execute `dataFrame.unpersist` when you complete using it.

Comment: I'll write an answer then.

Comment: good point, oo I almost forgot to add the unpersist in my code :P thanks though, great tips

yep go ahead !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark merges `sparkSession.sql(queryTimeRange)` and `dataSet.filter(dataSet("event_time").between(dtRangeStart, dtRangeEnd))` into one command which in cql looks like:

> SELECT "sensorid", "event_time", "value" FROM "company_5a819ee2522e572c8a16a43a"."data" WHERE token("sensorid") > ? AND token("sensorid") <= ? AND "event_time" >= ? AND "event_time" >= ? AND "event_time" <= ?

And there you get two same restrictions on the same field `"event_time" >= ?`.

If you persist `dataFrame` before the execution of `.filter` Spark will compute `dataFrame` separately from `.filter`:

```
val dataFrame = sparkSession.sql(queryTimeRange)
dataFrame.persist
dataFrame.filter(dataSet("event_time").between(dtRangeStart, dtRangeEnd))
```

Comment: How does it look like?

Comment: It just gives the same error as without a persist call, I am doing a persist DISK_ONLY (if that makes any diff)

Comment: Are you filtering persisted dataset?

Comment: Also, you can try to add dataFrame.count()  between persist and filtering to force dataFrame computation.